# Disable certain features of PHP Markdown

Tags: php, markdown

I'm using the [classic version](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/classic/) of PHP Markdown and PHP Markdown Extra. I've tried reading through the [configuration docs](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/configuration/) but can't find out how to disable the [footnote feature](https://michelf.ca/projects/php-markdown/extra/#footnotes).

a) Is it possible to disable the footnote feature and b) How can I do that?

My code so far is:

```
$parser = new MarkdownExtra_Parser;

$parser->tab_width = 2;
$parser->no_markup = true;
$html = $parser->transform( $text );
```

Hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: You could use js to hide them `$('.footnotes').hide();`, but otherwise not sure.

Comment: Thanks for the idea but I'd prefer to disable the feature altogether if possible?

Comment: What about re-parsing the generated HTML and then using that to remove the footnote element ? Definitely not the most elegant solution but better than @Dan 's JS solution.

Comment: Doesn't Dan's suggestion parse the generated HTML and 'hide' the footnote element?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't find another way to do what you want, I made another PHP parser with complex configuration (in INI files). It is not so documented yet ... sorry. But it may do what you expect.

You can find it at [github.com/piwi/markdown-extended](http://github.com/piwi/markdown-extended).

To do your stuff, make a copy of the `src/MarkdownExtended/Resources/config/markdown_config.full.ini` file and edit it by commenting all the `filter:Note:...` statements of the gamuts stacks (at the bottom of the file).

Then just run:

```
\MarkdownExtended\MarkdownExtended::create(array('config_file'=>'path/to/your/file'))
    ->transformString($text)
    ->getBody();
```

Hope this can help.